# How to create a directory with 777 permissions?

Tags: linux, assembly, directory, x86-64, umask

I want to create directory with permission 777.

The code below is creating the directory, but not with permissions I asked for.

```
section .text
global _start:
_start:
             mov rax,83 ;syscall number for directory
             mov rdi,chaos ; dir name
             mov esi,00777Q ;permissions for directory
             syscall
             mov rax,60
             mov rdi,0
             syscall
section .data
           chaos:db 'somename'
```

Comment: Works fine here although you should put a zero terminator after the directory name. You might also be confused by the `umask` setting being applied on top of what you specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's `man 2 mkdir`:

> The argument `mode` specifies the mode for the new directory (see inode(7)).  It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode of  the created  directory is `(mode & ~umask & 0777)`.

Basically, both your program and your user can veto each permission bit:

- You can say which bits you are comfortable with by passing them to `mkdir`
- The user can say which bits they are comfortable with by setting the `umask`
- Only bits that you both agree on will be set on the final directory.

Therefore:

- If you run `umask 0000` before running your program, your directory will be `0777`.
- If you run `umask 0027` your directory will be `0750`.
- If you want to force your directory to be `777` against the user's wishes, you have to `chmod("somename", 0777)` in a separate step.

Comment: You could also first set the umask to 0 by invoking `umask(0)` from inside the program.